# Store query param value in React app localStorage and update the state after visiting multiple times

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, local-storage, query-string

In my React app I have a banner. From a certain system users are redirected to this React app, to certain pages. Within those redirect url's we add a *query param* e.g: `?redirectFrom=my-site`.

Then in React when a user has been redirected for e.g `2` times we don't show the banner anymore.

How should I implement this? I was thinking about storing it in `localStorage`. But how to determine and save the x amount of redirects from a user?

**Update:**
So far the banner is shown when the url has the query param `redirectFrom=my-site` and after clicking the close button, it doesn't show anymore:

```
  import queryString from 'query-string';

  const queryParams = queryString.parse(location.search);

  const [show, setShow] = useState(true);

  const hasQueryParam = queryString
    .stringify(queryParams)
    .includes('redirectFrom=my-site');

  const showBanner = show && hasQueryParam;

  useEffect(() => {
    const data = localStorage.getItem('MY_APP_STATE');

    if (data !== null) {
      setShow(JSON.parse(data));
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('MY_APP_STATE', JSON.stringify(show));
  }, [show]);

  return (
   {showBanner && <MyBanner onClick={() => setShow(false)} />}
  );
```

But now how to add the logic to count x amount of times a user has used a url which contains `redirectFrom=my-site`? For example after 2 times don't show the banner anymore? I do have to create another `localStorage` item right?

How do I achieve this?

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong can't you check your Cookies if you have for example cookie called redirected if no set it to 1 else if yes set it to it's value +1 and the banner you check if you don't have it or you have it less than your certain number e.g 2

Answer (score 0):

1. User is redirected to page `www.my-react-app.com?redirectFrom=my-site`, in this scenario the referrer is `my-site`
2. The react app checks whether a local storage named `MY_REACT_APP_STORAGE` exists
3. If a local storage named `MY_REACT_APP_STORAGE` doesn't exist, create one:

```js
var storageData = {};
var url_string = window.location.href; 
var url = new URL(url_string);
var referrer = url.searchParams.get("redirectFrom");
storageData[referrer] = 1;
localStorage.setItem("MY_REACT_APP_STORAGE", JSON.stringify(storageData));
```

4. If a local storage named `MY_REACT_APP_STORAGE` does exist, check if the the react app has already been redirected to from the same referrer and update the storage accordingly:

```js
var url_string = window.location.href; 
var url = new URL(url_string);
var referrer = url.searchParams.get("redirectFrom");
var storageData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("MY_REACT_APP_STORAGE"));
if (!storageData[referrer]) {
  storageData[referrer] = 1;
} else {
  storageData[referrer] = storageData[referrer] + 1;
}
localStorage.setItem("MY_REACT_APP_STORAGE", JSON.stringify(storageData));
```

5. In the react app you can render the banner only if the app is being visited for the first time by the referrer site:

```js
// ...
render() {
  var url_string = window.location.href; 
  var url = new URL(url_string);
  var referrer = url.searchParams.get("redirectFrom");
  var storageData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("MY_REACT_APP_STORAGE"));
  var bannerCSS = {
    display: 'none'
  };
  if (!storageData[referrer] || storageData[referrer] < 2) {
    bannerCSS.display = 'block';
  }

  return (<div>
    <div id="banner" style={bannerCSS}>...</div>
  </div>);
}
// ...
```